# Explanation for extracting data from twitter search API and printing on the HTML using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter

I am pretty new to javascript and jquery. I am making a web app which requires data from the twitter. Here are two codes that i have. The first one is from a friend and the other one is my version. Now my version isnt working. So here are my few questions:

1) In version 1, why do we are passing e to the function ? 
2) Why do we use "jsonp" in dataType ?
3) What makes my code not working ?

and

What makes code version 1 working?

**Working Version**

```
$('#input').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
       var hashtag = $(this).find('input[name="hashtag"]').val();
        var twitterapi = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?";
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: twitterapi,
          data: {
            "q": hashtag,
            "rpp": 1000
          },
          dataType: 'jsonp'
        }).done(function (response) {
          var results = response.results;
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            $("#tweet").append("<p class='tweet'>" +
              "<span class='username'>" +
              results[i].from_user +
              "</span> <span class='tweet_content'> " +
              results[i].text + "</span></p>");
          }
        });
```

**My version**

```
var hashtag = $(this).find('input[name="hashtag"]').val();
        var twitterapi = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?";
        var tweetspresent = results.length;
         jQuery.ajax(
         {
              type: "GET",
              url: twitterapi ,
              data: {"q": hashtag,"rpp":1000},
              dataType: 'jsonp',
            });
        }).done(function(results)
            {
               for(i=0;i<tweetspresent;i++)
                 {
                   $("#tweet").html("<p> Name: " + results[i].from_user + " - " + results[i].text + "</p>");
                 }
            });
});
```

Comment: I can resume them all by saying: please, first learn DOM and JavaScript (in that order.) This is a matter of not understanding the basics, search through [so] and you'll find all those answers

Answer (score 0):

1) The "e" stands for *event*, in this case it is the *submit* event Object that is passed into the function. You can find more information about events [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp). [Here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) is a more explanation what for instance the preventDefault method does.

2) When you are obtaining data using ajax call from a different domain (for instance your-website.com executes javascript that gets data from twitter.com), we speak of "cross-domain" request. For security reasons this is not allowed. There are several methods how to go around this issue. One of them is [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). With newer browsers that have native support for [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) you don't need to use the jsonp type anymore.

3) You don't say what is not working, so do a little debugging first (in modern browser) using console.log(variable), check if your done callback gets called, if it does, log the response to see what is the structure (or better check twitter api).

**EDIT**
You don't have to pass anything into `done` function - that only depends on your needs. When you execute the jQuery.ajax function it will do what ever you told it to do and when it finishes it returns Object(s) that you can use further. In your case you need a way to access the data returned from Twitter. I strongly suggest that you do more reading on jQuery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Can you please explain me that in the code 1 why we are passing "result" to the function after .done() ?